# xamarin.forms Relase version of android app doesnt render some texts and crashes on button (debug works fine)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have this app that I am working on for a while. I am testing it now in release mode and I am seeing some weired behavior

On one list i have in a master detail page

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Padding="15,10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
          <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                Text="{Binding Title}" 
                d:Text="{Binding .}"
                 TextColor="#828282"
                 FontFamily="Galvji-01.ttf"
                FontSize="18"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The text that is supposed to render here with the menu is not showing up on release mode. it does work fine in debug, but on release the list with the texts is just empty.

Also, there is a button that is supposed to bring you to a new screen and that crashes the app on release but works totally fine on debug.

So I guess this has nothing to do with code but with the settings. I have not changed any settings in this project.

Can you please help me here?

Than you!

Comment: There are many crashes which only occurs in Release mode, not in debug mode mode(like incorrect date parsing, app crash on Release but not in Debug mode). You can try adding any sdk for fetching the crash reports. Use Microsoft crashlytics, its easy to implement & really helpful

Comment: Or the issue maybe within `d:Text="{Binding .}"` Can you explain whats this? And add its bindable property in question

Comment: Try to remove the `FontFamily="Galvji-01.ttf"` line and test to check if the project will work fine.To use the custom font in xamarin, you could refer the doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#use-a-custom-font